# Objects, Casting, Inheritance

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism

```
Dog d = new Dog(); // there's a toString() overridding Object's

ArrayList container = new ArrayList();

container.add(d);
container.get(0).toString; // calls toString() of Dog, however the Object is not cast to Dog
```

Why does it call `Dog`'s `toString()` if the runtime type is `Object`? I know every object is a subclass of `Object`, but now we are working with the superclass, aren't we?

Comment: *Why does it calls Dog's toString() if the runtime type is Object?* -- Because the type is not `Object`.  You put a `Dog` in, you get a `Dog` out.

Comment: I think you need to read a tutorial on [Method Overriding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding).

Comment: The runtime type is *not* `Object`. The *declared* type is `Object` but the runtime type of the object is always `Dog`.

Comment: When instance methods like `toString` are called on an object, Java always uses the _real_ underlying type of the object to decide which implementation to use, not the type of the reference.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Then why do i need to cast the Object to make Dog's unique methods available?

Comment: @BenyBosko Because at *compile time*, the compiler doesn't know that the object will always be a `Dog`... it sees that the object is declared as an `Object`, and it makes zero assumptions about what the subclass could be. At *runtime*, however, the program knows what the underlying subclass is, so it uses the appropriate method.

Comment: @BenyBosko, what methods are available to be called is determined at compile time based on the reference type.  What implementations of those methods are used is determined at runtime from the object's real type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object is the compile-time type of your variable. This means that if you'll try to run some method from `Dog` that does not belong to `Object` on `container.get(0)`, you'll get compilation error.

However, once you're compiled, the run-time type is the actual type of the instance, in this case it is Dog, so you'll get Dog's toString().

The idea is that d is a reference to some object in memory (of type `Dog`). when you compile it, the reference is of type `Object`, so you can call only `Object` methods. but when you run it- the program will go to the actual object and run it's method- and this one is `Dog`

Answer (score 4):

---

---

No, the type of the object doesn't change, it simply remains `Dog`. The fact that we store an object with an `Object` reference doesn't mean that `d` has lost its real type.

For example:

```
Dog d = new Dog();
Object dObj = d; // object is referenced by an Object reference but is still a Dog
dObj.toString(); // calls real method (Dog)
```

Please think about this in this way as it was real life:

- You have a `Dog` and a `Cat`, which are both `Animal`
- When you talk about your pets with your friends you refer to your `Dog` and your `Cat` as your `Animal`s
- When you tell how your animals give their noise, they still give their noise as a `Cat` or a `Dog` (so cat meows and dog barks), not as a generic `Animal`. They stay who they are despite being referenced as `Animals`.

Answer (score 3):

When you create an object of type `Dog`, the object created will be of type `Dog`, period. Methods in Java are virtual by default and they will be called polymorphically.

```
Object obj = new Dog();
String s =  obj.toString(); // dog's toString will be called
```

Try upcasting it,

```
Dog dog = new Dog();
Object obj = (Object)dog; 
String s =  obj.toString(); // dog's toString will be called
```

and nothing will change.

And btw, you using a [raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) and that is considered harmful

Comment: In fact, Java, unlike C++ or Object Pascal, only has *virtual* instance methods.

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing

```
container.add(d);
```

Does it add an object or Dog ? Ans: An object of Dog type

Similarly when you do `container.get(0)` it returns an object of Dog Type and hence it's toString method is called.

Answer (score 0):

All classes are an extension of `java.lang.Object`, when you make a class it automatically puts next to it `extends java.lang.Object`. You can think of it as either an `Object` or `Dog`, but personally I think of it as a specialized `Object`, as you are adding new methods, variables, and code that wasn't there before. It also means that your `Dog` class contains all the methods listed here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html